# jQuery UI Modal Dialogs in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Excuse me for the simplistic question, but I've had a hard time getting my head around this. I have a View (.cshtml) with the following contents (Per this [sample](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-and-ajax-real-world-example/)):

```
<div id='dlgLogin'>
    <h1>Log in</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("username")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>@Html.Password("password")</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dlgLogin").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                Login: function () {
                    // perform login
                    $.post("@Url.Action("Login", "Home")",
                    {
                        username: $('#username').val(),
                        password: $('#password').val()
                    },
                    function( data, status, xhr ) {
                        if(data.Success){
                            alert('great'); // do something
                            $('#dlgLogin').dialog("close");
                            $('#divLoginButton').load("@Url.Action("GetLoginButton", "Home")");
                        } else {
                            // do something else
                        }
                    });
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically the View will always load in a jQuery UI Dialog whenever it's opened, that is, it's the responsibility of the View itself to place it's own content inside a jQuery UI dialog. I've done this so that I can override the `OnAuthorzation()` event of my Log In and redirect the user to a pop up when they are required to log in.  I have 3 questions:

**1.** How would I display a loading animation (a .gif) when the form is posted back to the server? With this approach?  I'm aware that if I used an `Ajax.BeginForm` I could have specified a `UpdateTargetId` which would have been used as an area to load the animation during post back, but how would I achieve that effect with this approach?

**2.** How would I attach and handle the `success` event to the form post above? i.e. When the form is posted back to the `Login` Action of the `Home` Controller.

**3.** I've seeing at least 3 or 4 different approaches to displaying dialogs in MVC. What is the correct way to do this? Is the approach that I posted above considered good/mvc-friendly practise, if not what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 How would I display a loading animation (a .gif) when the form is posted back to the server?

Take a look at [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/):

```
<div id="loader"></div>

$("#loader").bind("ajaxSend", function () {
    $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function () {
    $(this).hide();
}).bind("ajaxError", function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

> 2 How would I attach and handle the success event to the form post above?

I don't understand what you are asking. You have attached an anonymous function to handle the post to the server in your sample code.

> 3 I've seeing at least 3 or 4 different approaches to displaying dialogs in MVC. What is the correct way to do this?

There is no *best* way of showing a dialog.
You can use the approach you showed with loading the dialog content with the page, but i would add a `style="display: none;"` to the dialogs `div`. Another approach would be to load the dialog content with ajax from a partial view when opening the dialog.

Comment: Yep, `ajaxSend` was what I was looking for, thanks. And yes, you're right, the sample I posted handles the callback itself so my second question was nonsense (I posted this at 4am). Could you [have a look at this](http://ricardocovo.com/2012/04/06/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms-razor-version/) and give me an opinion on it? I really like the way it's displaying the dialogs, allowing you to do something on the parent page (displaying the twitter like message in this case).

Comment: Yes, thats basically the second approach i suggested: Load the content  as a partial view into the dialog. The interaction with the masterpage is done by returning a JSONResult to th edit/post action and fiddling with some javascript.